# Is profile data automatically retrieved only for current user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-profiles

1) I assume profile data is automatically retrieved only for current user, while profile data for other users must be retrieved manually?

2)
I’m not sure what the following quote is trying to convey:

> If you define a profile in web.config file that doesn’t exist in the serialized profile information, the ProfileModule will just use the default value

- I assume “serialized profile information” refers to profile data stored in database? If so, then I assume quote refers to situation where code accesses for the first time Profile object and Asp.Net tries to retrieve complete profile data? And if there isn’t any profile data stored in DB for that particular profile, ProfileModule will return default values for profile-properties?

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. The `Profile` property of the `Page` class returns the profile data for the current user.
2. Yes.